# Objects rotating after falling on another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I make a rotation of object with gravity when the object falls on a slope.

For example. here is what I want to happen:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            this.box_speed++;

            if(this.box_speed > 0){
            //check ground
            for (i = 0; i < this.box_speed; i++) {
                if(!this.terrain_bmp.hitTest(new Rectangle(this.box.x,this.box.y + 20,10,1))){
                    this.box.y += 1;
                }else{
                    this.box_speed = 0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for (i = 0; i < Math.abs(this.box_speed); i++) {
                if(!this.terrain_bmp.hitTest(new Rectangle(this.box.x,this.box.y,10,1))){
                    this.box.y -= 1;
                }
                else{
                    this.box_speed = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need it for educational purposes? If not, I would go for physics library for best results. There are people who spent weeks and weeks to achieve realistic effects.

Comment: I made a mistake...I'm working on a 2D game and I just want to rotate the object when it touches the ground, as I drew in the picture.

Comment: Use a library for physics, it will save your life.

Comment: If you work on it on your own, you'll probably achieve artificial-looking effect anyway, remember what happens to a box when it exits the slope. It should slide through it, part of it hovering over the floor, not just change the angle instantly.

Comment: The hit test should identify the hitting corner. The angle between the slope and the rectangle bottom plus the combination of hitting corner and sign of the slope is the information needed for a 2D rotation matrix. translate the origin of your coordinate system to the hitting corner, rotate, invert the initial translation and apply this sequence of operations to the hitting rectangle's coordinates. This will only work in the simplified setting of straight line geometry and the 'falling' rectangle being aligned with the coordinate axes. As has been said, there are libraries for such operations.

Comment: +1 for the library for physics! ... look into game engines: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines